# Batch file to list and copy files to another directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm a novice with batch files, even though I've had a computer since the mid 1980s. I need to create a (preferably simple) batch file that will list all the directories on drive D:\TAR\ (to a text file maybe?) and append the extension .tar to the directories names. Then I would like to copy all the .tar files(in the text file that was created) on E:\Incomplete\File1.tar to F:\ToComplete\ directory.

I tried doing it from a DOS command prompt, but I couldn't figure out how to put the .tar extension on the directory names and do the copying. I've been googleing, and searching on this site, with no similar problems.

Is there a list on the net that list most of the commands that can be used in .bat files, for example @echo, end, if, then, etc.? I would like to be able have it as a guide. I would appreciate any and all help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The command prompt has a builtin `help` command that provides a decent listing of common commands, and each command supports the `/?` switch to attain more information on it.

You will typically use the `for` command to enumerate the contents of a directory, and if you need to perform string manipulation on the directory entries you will probably find the command prompt's "delayed expansion" feature useful.  This feature is off by default, but can be enabled for an interactive session by running `cmd /v:on`.  (Enabling this feature permanently requires a registry setting.)

In terms of your specific problem here, when you say "all the directories under D:\TAR\", would that be a recursive operation?